# Spring boot jpa the FK pointing at the wrong PK

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, relationship

Hi when I adding two list to my ListA tabell where I use Rest Api ListA, the first list have id 1 and the other list have id 2

After I execute rest api for ListB just one time and also adding data from id 2 from ListA. I get status 200 in postman with right details.

When I looking at my database I see that the FK is pointing at wrong PK from tabell ListA instead pointing at PK id 2 its pointing PK id 1 in tabell ListA.

**Summary**

My FK in ListB is not pointing at the right PK in tabell ListA

```
@MapsId
@JoinColumn(name = "listA_fk")
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private ListA listA;


@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="listA")
@JsonIgnore
private ListB ListB;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what @MapsId , shared id,remove @MapsId.

Comment: Thanks the problem was ListA should not have mapsid, ListA contains already 8 entity thats are in mapsid and ListB have also 8 entity thats are in mapsid but I wanted to add ListA to it so it worked when I removed mapsid on ListA

Comment: You upvote and mark it as correct answer then :)